# Second Master-Detail Scheme Does Not Load Correctly in SplitViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a master-detail application setup in a split view controller that is basically Swift standard code. With the initial master-detail scheme it works as expected.

I want to load a Second Master with it's Second Detail in the left and right panes of the split view controller. With one major exception it is working as expected. The exception is that the second detail view only covers the second master in the left pane. The second detail does not load in the right pane.

Here's the issue graphically. The first master-detail scheme:
[image]

Then when the second master is launched:
[image]

Then when a cell is tapped in the second master:
[image]

I load the second master from a MVC1 button with a simple storyboard segue, though I've done it programmatically as a delegate. Nothing has worked to show master 2 on the left and detail 2 on the right. In all cases, I have tried the segue as Show and as Show Detail. I can't discern a difference in the app behavior.

[image]

For the segue from MVC2 to DVC2:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "showKeywordDetail" {

        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {

            let object = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Keyword
            let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! KeywordDetailViewController

            controller.detailItem = object
            //controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem()
            controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = false
            controller.sentBy = "showKeywordDetail"

        }//if let indexPath

    } else if segue.identifier == "addKeyword" {
```

//bunch more code for other cases

}

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to this solution seems to be creating a separate "non-connected" master detail scheme.

On the original master, place a button with an action:

```
@IBAction func doCodeKeywordPush(sender : AnyObject) {
 self.navigationController!.pushViewController(self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("KeywordTableViewController") as! UITableViewController, animated: true)

}//doCodeKeywordPush
```

Then make the second master-detail scheme a stand alone set in the storyboard. Embed the second master view controller in a navigation controller. Create a segue from the second master tableViewCell to the second detail view controller. There should be no segue or connection between the button and the second group.

Finally, configure the second master to second detail segue as any other setup.